# Robot framework: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position

Tags: robotframework, non-ascii-characters

I have issue running curl command in Robot framework containing UTF-8 symbols:

Run And Return Rc And Output    curl -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" -X POST -d '{"user_name":"User_ÈØ","password":"abc123"}' "https://test.com/test/prov/account"

This result in error:

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character

I am using robotframework 4.1.3; robotframework-seleniumlibrary 5.1.3; python 3.6.8

Answer (score 0):

You can use following keyword to get this working: First  you can put your data into variable with encoding string to byte and then pass it to POST.

```
${bytes} =  Encode String To Bytes  ${string}   UTF-8   
${bytes} =  Encode String To Bytes  ${string}   ASCII   errors=ignore
```

More detailed documentation is at - https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html#Encode%20String%20To%20Bytes

Comment: Unfortunately in this method we ignore errors special characters; they are removed and I do wanted to create user containing them. And yes, I forgot to emphasize that part in my question.
My final solution was:
Create File  ${file_name}  {"user_name":"User_ÈØ","password":"abc123"}
This allows putting UTF-8 symbols in file without errors. Then in curl command you just read payload from file "-d @${file_name}"